# Is it possible to identify |ψ⟩ of a single photon with the coherent state |z⟩?

Tags: photons, quantum-optics

In [this paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.16778), it is claimed that, for a single photon, we can not connect $\left| \psi \right>$ with electric and magnetic field.

Is it possible to identify $\left| \psi \right>$ of a single photon with the coherent state $\left| z \right>$?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not.  Even assuming photons of a single frequency $\omega$, the coherent state 
$$
\vert\alpha\rangle =e^{-\vert\alpha\vert^2/2}\sum_{n} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\vert n\rangle
$$
is clearly a *superposition* of states $\vert n\rangle$ containing $ n$ photons having this frequency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that means I can not explain the interference caused by a single photon passing through double slit in the light of quantum optics.....is it?

Comment: @anik I recovered the paper. It might take a while before I get to it but I'll update in due time.